# Xamarin Android: No Activity found to handle Intent (Google Pay) | Intent.CreateChooser

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android, google-pay, upi

I am creating Xamarin Android application. I have a functionality to accept payments from UPI only.
Problem I am facing is, it works for some device and fails for few device.
I have tested with Realme X2 (Working) and Redmi Note 8 (Not working now).

Initially it was working for Redmi Note 8 few days earlier. Now there was an update for Google Pay and Device both, now it is not working. But same works with Realme X2 with same scenario.

It throws exception as below.

```
{Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=upi://pay?pa=xxxxxxx@okhdfcbank&pn=XYZStoreStore&tn=20041901232493241&am=1.00&cu=INR pkg=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user }
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <26521a5118b44c858c385715922b9d5d>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <26521a5118b44c858c385715922b9d5d>:0 
  at Android.App.Activity.StartActivityForResult (Android.Content.Intent intent, System.Int32 requestCode) [0x00044] in <4ccdb3137d974856b786e1aeebbfbab6>:0 
  at WalletActivity.PayWithGPay (Models.Wallet wallet) [0x000c2] in \WalletActivity.cs:302 
  --- End of managed Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException stack trace ---
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=upi://pay?pa=xxxxxxx@okhdfcbank&pn=XYZStoreStore&tn=20041901232493241&am=1.00&cu=INR pkg=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2016)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1677)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4652)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4610)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Here is my code:

```
private static string GOOGLE_TEZ_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user";
private static int TEZ_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

    try
{

    if (wallet.WalletAmount > 0)
    {
        RefrenceID = AndroidHelper.GetReferenceID();
        Android.Net.Uri uri =
        new Android.Net.Uri.Builder()
            .Scheme("upi")
            .Authority("pay")
            .AppendQueryParameter("pa", "xxxxxxx@okhdfcbank")
            .AppendQueryParameter("pn", "XYZStore")
            //.AppendQueryParameter("mc", "1234")
            //.AppendQueryParameter("tr", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"))
            .AppendQueryParameter("tn", RefrenceID)
            .AppendQueryParameter("am", WalletAmount)
            .AppendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
            .Build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetData(uri);
        intent.SetPackage(GOOGLE_TEZ_PACKAGE_NAME);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, TEZ_REQUEST_CODE);

        // Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        // upiPayIntent.SetData(uri);

        // Intent chooser = Intent.CreateChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");


        // if (null != chooser.ResolveActivity(this.PackageManager))
            // StartActivityForResult(chooser, TEZ_REQUEST_CODE);
        // else
            // Toast.MakeText(this, "No UPI app found, please install one to continue", ToastLength.Long).Show();

    }
}
catch (Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Google Pay application not found, kindly Install", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Exception Occured - E1002", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Kindly help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have google pay installed on your device?